# Getting "mkdir home/user permission denied" on go get command

Tags: go

I have set the following environmental variables in `.bashrc` file

```sh
    export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
    export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
    export GOPATH=/home/Rushikesh/GO
    export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

When I run following command:

```sh
    go get github.com/nsf/gocode
```

I get the following error:

```
    package github.com/nsf/gocode: mkdir /home/Rushikesh: permission denied
```

Comment: 1. Are you running the `go get` command as the user `Rushikesh`?

Comment: I tried running command from both `/home` and `/home/Rushikesh`. I have created a `GO` folder in `Rushikesh` directory.

Comment: I do not mean the directory you run the command from. I mean, which user are you logged in as when you run the command and what are the file permissions set for the `/home/Rushikesh/GO/` folder

Comment: I haven't set any permission for `/home/Rushikesh/GO/`. the permission are default set by OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your configuration.

As reading form your comments Rushikesh is not user it is your directory.
Then the GOPATH env variable should be

`export GOPATH=/home/logged_user_name/Rushikesh/GO`

Answer (score 0):

Facing `go: could not create module cache: mkdir /home/josh: permission denied` issue in my Linux machine

RCA - invalid `GOPATH` in goenv

Solution -

**Step 1**

- go to your working directory and enter following command

> `pwd`

Copy the working directory

eg -
[image]

**Step 2**

> `sudo vi ~/.bashrc`

paste following command in `.bashrc` file

> `export GOPATH="<your working directory or paste here the pwd output>"`

eg - export GOPATH="/home/josh/workspace"

**Step 3**

> `source ~/.bashrc`